# Taking users input via Form, Validating in a PHP File then using in another PHP File

Tags: php

I'm sourcing information on how to use data from a FORM inside a PHP file named "receive_data.php" to validate a POST request (POST has already been validated). I will then use the data that "receive_data.php" has validated to then send to another PHP file named "Data_base.php" to export to a text file. So basically I am wondering how to use the variables from one PHP file in another PHP with `class Database`.

Snipits of what i have:

**Recieve_data.php**

```
if (isset($_POST)) {

    $userName = getField('username');
    $userAge = getField('age');
    $userEmail = getField('email');
    $userPhone = getField('phone');
}

function getField($fieldName)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$fieldName])) {
        return trim($_POST[$fieldName]);
    }
    return '';
}


if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if (!ctype_alpha($_POST['username']) || (strlen($_POST['username']) < 2) || (strlen($_POST['username']) > 100)) {
        send_error($response400, $message3);
    }
} //Data checked if POST and validated unsure how to use in another php file
```

I've used `include "recieve_data.php";`however i can't seem to access `$userName` in `data_base.php`let alone the class.

Comment: Do you want to pass the variables from one class to another? Is that what you ask?

Comment: I don't have a class in Recieve_data.php and i have a class called database in data_base.php. Im just trying to use the variables from a form validated in recieve_data inside the class of database in file data_base.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the variables in your `Database` class you can work with a constructor.

Example `data_base.php`:

```
class Database {

    function __construct($username, $age, $email, $phone)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        echo "Username: ".$this->username;
    }

}
```

Now you can create an instance of your `Database` class like this:

```
$database = new Database("Foo", 19, "foo@example.com", 1234567);
```

Now you can use the data everywhere in your class.

For Example:

```
public function someFunction() {
        echo "Username: ".$this->username; //output: "Foo"
    }
```

This call will take the username that you passed with the new instance (in this case "Foo").

Edit: But you can't use `$this->username` (for example) in a static context.

So

```
public static function someOtherFunction() {
    echo "Age: ".$this->age;
}
```

will not work! In this case you have to work with getters and setters.

Comment: The constructor accepts pretty much any data you give him for the values:)